# How to select an element with jQuery in the same way as $(this)?

Tags: jquery, this

okay, so, I've got this (Wordpress powered) website that's got some images on it. I want to scale these images once they're at the point of overflowing the content div. To make them scale properly, luckily I can just add a class `.scaled` that will make the image `width:100%;`, and that'll take care of the problem.

My problem is that, when I'm detecting if an image is too big for the page, I can't seem to select just that particular image on the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="entry-content">
   <p>
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Luftballong.jpg" width="1024" height="768" class="alignnone">
   </p>
</div>
```

CSS that matters:

```
.scaled {
   width:100%;
 }
```

Now, for the jQuery. I currently have it set up like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($('section .entry-content img').width() > $('.entry-content').width()) {
        $(this).addClass('scaled')
    }
});
```

My problem lies, as it often does, with `$(this)`. I'm guessing it doesn't select the actual image here, but rather something else, or nothing in particular.

So my question is, **What's the best way to select just one image with jQuery, and apply a class to it?** I'd love to see something that would just involve me changing the `$(this)` to something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're in the scope of `$(window)`, an if statement does not change the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your jQuery method to this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $( "section .entry-content img" ).each(function() {
        if($(this).width() > $('.entry-content').width()) {
            $(this).addClass('scaled')
        }
    });
});
```

This should process the function for (and with "this" being relative to) each of the individual img elements.

Comment: Yes! This works flawlessly, thank you so much! I should not that I did change on bracket, the one after `$(this).width()`. That bracket was messing up the code, making me panic. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Oh, whoops, yeah, my bad on the typo. I've updated my original answer with the fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('section .entry-content img').filter(function() {
        return $(this).width() > $(this).closest('.entry-content').width();
    }).addClass('scaled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a variable like:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var $img = $('section .entry-content img')[0];
  if($img.width() > $('.entry-content').width()) {
    $img.addClass('scaled')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already a bunch of good answers here for a function that does what you want, but I thought it would be worth adding that the keyword `this` in the context of an event callback function refers to a DOM element passed in by JQuery. So in your previous example, `$(this)` actually resulted in a JQuery object wrapping the `window` element.

Consequently, as you can see in the many other examples, the solution was to change the selector of the JQuery object from which you were using `this`.